# Python function for 7zip compression

Tags: python

I wrote a function in Python to call 7zip to compress a folder. The code works and is able to perform the task, however I do not know if this is the most optimal way. Are there any ways to improve the code, any redundant steps?

```
def Compress_7z(Initial_path,Container_Name,File_List, compression_level = -1,DAC = False):
 """Compression level = -1 standard, 0-9 compression level
       DAC : Delete After Compression - Remove File after being compressed
    """ 
    try:
        chdir(Initial_path)
    except:
        return('Path does not exist')

    # write a listfile
    with open('list.txt', 'w') as f:
        for item in File_List:
            f.write("%s\n" % item)

    cmd = ['7z', 'a', Container_Name,'@list.txt']

    if compression_level != -1 and compression_level <= 9:
        cmd.append('-mx{0}'.format(compression_level))
    elif compression_level > 9 or compression_level < -1:
        return("Compression not standard: aborting compression")

    system = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)

    while system.poll() == None:  # .poll() will return a value once it's complete. 
        time.sleep(1)
    if DAC:
        for f in File_List:
            remove(f)

    # Clean up from compression
    remove('list.txt')
    return(system.communicate())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply reading the code already has a few things which stand out to me
(in general this all goes towards the style described in
[this document](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), which is
standard to follow for Python code):

- `Compress_7z` should start lower-case and probably should also say
  `compress_7zip`.  I'm agreeing that the literal "7" would be
  appropriate here, given the format name.
- `DAC` is a bad variable name, as you've to read the docstring to even
  begin to understand what this parameter is doing.  A better name might
  be, well, `delete_files_after` perhaps.
- The rest of the parameters should also all be lower-case.
- Try and apply consistent formatting, or use an IDE or
  [command-line tool](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to do it
  for you (right now there's no whitespace after some of the commas for
  example, also some of the quotes are single and some are double for no
  good reason).
- The docstring is not very standard, though at least it mentions the
  value range of the parameters, which is obviously good.

Next up, actual functionality:

Shelling out to the `7z` utility is of course an option, although there
are also pure Python libraries for this as far as I can see.  The reason
I point this out is that for one the command-line utility might not be
installed and e.g. `pip` or a similar tool for Python might make it
easier to handle the dependency.

Since you've already settled on it though, a few more points about the
current implementation:

- `chdir` in a library function is almost certainly a bad idea.  It's
  completely not expected that "compress these files" also means "change
  my current working directory".  Instead make sure that the function
  works without by specifying file names reliably (that is, using
  absolute path names, or by specifying the working directory *for the
  invoked process only*).
- Using strings as error values is a big no.  Use exceptions, or if you
  absolutely do not want to do that, a properly structured return
  value.  Right now you couldn't distinguish the return value of the
  tool from the strings `"Path does not exist"` and that's generally to
  be avoided.
- If the compression level is a string the `list.txt` file will not be
  cleaned up.  That's why you generally want to handle exceptions
  properly, look up how
  [`try`, `catch` and `finally` work](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)
  for that.
- Finally it seems like the `subprocess.Popen` invocation is too much
  work.  If you don't have to communicate with the invoked process,
  simply run it and wait for the result. `time.sleep` is an extremely
  wasteful way of accomplishing the same.  Instead I think you might
  just be able to use `subprocess.run` with the `cwd` argument (see
  above) and be done with it.  You don't need `shell=True` either, since
  the invocation doesn't use any shell features at all.